# Salesforce validation rule for US and International Phone Number Regex not accepting spaces

Tags: regex, validation, salesforce

I have a validation rule checking for 10 digit US phone numbers, 11 Digit US and Canadian phone numbers and international phone numbers beginning with a + where the country code did not begin with a 1, they want dashes and spaces allowed.  my validation rule seems to be working except for allowing spaces.

```
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK( Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c)),
NOT(REGEX( Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c, "(\\d){10}")),  
NOT(REGEX(Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c,"^((\\1)?\\d{11})?$")),
NOT(
AND(
OR(
LEN(Physical_Service_Scheduling_Phone__c )=0,
REGEX(Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c, "^(\\+)([2-9])[0-9\\-\\s]+")
)
)
)
)
```

Comment: You could allow spaces between the numbers using for example `\b\d(?: *\d){9}\b` https://regex101.com/r/Fx352g/1

Answer (score 0):

I tested your validation function as written in a Sandbox. In testing, the  validation allows any value as the after hours phone, as long as the scheduling phone is blank. If the scheduling phone is not blank, it gives an error when I put spaces in the other field. I couldn't immediately see why when reviewing your code. Indentation helps me understand complicated functions, so let's start by adding some indentation so we can better see what the function is doing.

```
AND(
  NOT(ISBLANK(Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c)),
  NOT(REGEX(Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c, "(\\d){10}")),  
  NOT(REGEX(Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c, "^((\\1)?\\d{11})?$")),
  NOT(
    AND(
      OR(
        LEN(Physical_Service_Scheduling_Phone__c)=0,
        REGEX(Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c, "^(\\+)([2-9])[0-9\\-\\s]+")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Now we see there are four main criteria, with the fourth being more complicated than the others. Let's see how a sample after hours number of `555 555 1212` makes its way through this function, assuming the scheduling number is not blank.

```
NOT(ISBLANK(Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c))
```

The after hours number is not blank, so this evaluates to `NOT(False)` which is `True`.

```
NOT(REGEX(Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c, "(\\d){10}"))
```

If we omitted spaces, this would match the regexp; but the regexp doesn't allow spaces, so this evaluates as `NOT(False)` which is `True`. If you want to allow spaces, tell the pattern matcher where they can be. If the rule is intended to cover only North America numbers, we groups digits as 3-3-4. This would work: `"\\d{3}[ -]?\\d{3}[ -]?\\d{4}"`. Note that this precludes adding extension numbers and also allows haphazard spacing (`555555 5555`, `555-555 5555`, and `555-5555555` would all be acceptable), which may or may not meet your requirements. Continuing to the next criterion:

```
NOT(REGEX(Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c, "^((\\1)?\\d{11})?$"))
```

The number does not begin with 1 as required by this regexp, so this does not match and evaluates to `NOT(False)` which is `True`. This regexp also does not allow spaces and requires 11 digits following a `1`, which is not likely what you intended. There is no need to escape `1` with slashes. You could combine this with the above into a single regexp by prefixing it with `(1[ -]?)?`, making it optional to start with 1 but allow a space or dash if you do.

This brings us to the fourth criterion, which is a bit more complicated:

```
NOT(
  AND(
    OR(
      LEN(Physical_Service_Scheduling_Phone__c )=0,
      REGEX(Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c, "^(\\+)([2-9])[0-9\\-\\s]+")
    )
  )
)
```

If we assume the length of the scheduling phone is not 0 (i.e., we put something there), the first expression evaluates to `False`. And because the after hours number does not begin with a plus sign, it does not match the regexp, which also evaluates to `False`. We then end up with `NOT(AND(OR(False, False)))`, which is `True`. Incidentally, you can remove the `AND()` function, as it does not do anything useful.

With all four criteria solved, we now have `AND(True, True, True, True)`, which is `True`, thus signifying an error condition. While I have explained above which regexps need to be rewritten and how, in examining the fourth criteria, you should see another problem: As written, I don't see a way to fail when the scheduling number is blank. This is because when the scheduling number is blank, the fourth criterion always evaluates to `False`, and thus not an error, regardless of what is in the other field.

I would advise to do what I have done above: Break your problem down into smaller pieces and solve one at a time. You can use multiple validation rules to check this. For example:

```
AND(
  LEFT(Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c, 1) = "+",
  NOT(REGEXP(Physical_Service_After_Hours_Phone__c, "^\\+([2-9]|8[\\-\\s])[0-9\\-\\s]+")
)
```

This function checks the first character; if it is a +, it matches the first expression. Then, if it fails the regexp for international numbers, it also matches  the second expression and produces an error. On the other hand, if the first character is not a +, it will not match the first expression and continue to process other validation functions. (I also updated your regexp for international numbers to compensate for the fact that Russia has a single digit country code, leaving open the possibility that a user might follow it with a space or dash, per your original requirements.)

Alternatively, you could write a regexp to encompass both North America and international style numbers, but at the cost of legibility.